Retrieve User Domain Name in CloudFront Lambda@Edge for Origin Requests (SEO Modification)
I'm trying to retrieve the original user's domain name within a CloudFront Lambda@Edge function triggered by origin requests. I need this for SEO modifications in my static web app hosted on S3, but CloudFront seems to mask the domain name. How can I access the user's domain for targeted SEO adjustments?
I've tried using various Origin Request Policy options, including those that expose most headers, but none of them seem to provide the user's domain name

Assuming that you are attempting to find the domain used by client (ie. the information present in host header. When triggered with Viewer Request, the line request.headers.host.value should get you the hostname used by client. Sharing a code example for redirecting from domain1.com to domain2.com to show it in use.
async function handler(event) {
    const request = event.request
    const headers = request.headers
    const host = request.headers.host.value
    const uri = request.uri
    const newurl = 'https://domain2.com' + uri

    if (host === 'domain1.com') {
        console.log(host)
        console.log('redirecting to newsite')
        const response = {
            statusCode: 301,
            statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
            headers:
                { "location": { "value": newurl } }
            }

        return response // return the altered request
    }
    return request // allow everything else to continue to the origin
}

